# Sublime Text 2/3 - tag multiplier not working on tab

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I have just found something on my new Ubuntu installation that has not happened before. I will explain

Normally if i do this code:

```
div*3 and press tab
```

I get:

```
<div></div><div></div><div></div>
```

But now when I do the same thing, I get nothing. It just "tabs" over the line. This never happened before so if someone knows the answer I would be very thankful.

All this is happening with Emmet already installed

- Sublime Text 3: 3059
- Ubuntu 12.04 64 Bits

Same is also happening on Sublime Text2.

Comment: you need to install the emmett package and make sure you're editing an html, php, etc file.

Comment: I have already install EMMET package, i will edit the main

Answer (score 1):

Sublime Text does not come with the [`Emmet`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Emmet) package by default. You will need to install [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net) first - remember that there are different versions for [ST2](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation#st2) and [ST3](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation#st3). After it has been installed and you've restarted Sublime Text, open the Command Palette with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>, search for `Package Control: Install Package`, type in ***`emmet`***, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and it will be installed for you.

Comment: Emmet is already installed, i forgot to mention it, going to edit. Thanks